# sqlalchemy multiple databases with same table names not working

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-2.7

I have two databases that I'm working with in with Python using SQLAlchemy, the databases share table names and therefore I'm getting an error message when running the code.

The error message is :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'wo' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.
```

The simplified code is below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from mysql.connector.connection import MySQLConnection

Base = declarative_base()



def get_characterset_info(self):
    return self.get_charset()

MySQLConnection.get_characterset_info = MySQLConnection.get_charset


mysqlengine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://......../mp2', echo=True)
MYSQLSession = sessionmaker(bind=mysqlengine)     
mysqlsession= MYSQLSession()                      


MP2engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://......../mp2', echo=True)
MP2Session = sessionmaker(bind=MP2engine)     
mp2session= MP2Session()                      


class MYSQLWo(Base):
    __tablename__= 'wo'

    wonum = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    taskdesc = Column(String)    


    comments = relationship("MYSQLWocom", order_by="MYSQLWocom.wonum", backref='wo')



class MYSQLWocom (Base):
    __tablename__='wocom'

    wonum = Column(String, ForeignKey('wo.wonum'), primary_key=True)
    comments = Column(String, primary_key=True)





class MP2Wo(Base):
    __tablename__= 'wo'

    wonum = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    taskdesc = Column(String)    


    comments = relationship("MP2Wocom", order_by="MP2Wocom.wonum", backref='wo')


class MP2Wocom (Base):
    __tablename__='woc'

    wonum = Column(String, ForeignKey('wo.wonum'), primary_key=True)
    location = Column(String)
    sublocation1 = Column(String)
    texts = Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

How do I deal with databases having the same table structure?  I'm guessing it has something to do with the MetaData instance, but the SQLAlchemy documentation gets a little confusing when talking about the difference in the class declarative and classical usage..

Comment: I removed a random `)` in your source code I assume that was a typo if it's not it can be reverted.

Comment: I have the answer:
Since in reality the tables had slightly different structures, the solution was to simply create a separate declarative base.  If the tables indeed had the same structure, I would not have needed to create a separate class.  
    `Base = declarative_base()`  
    `Base2 = declarative_base()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since in reality the tables had different structures, the solution was to simply create a separate declarative base.  If the tables indeed had the same structure, I would have only needed one class for both tables.

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base2 = declarative_base() #this is all I needed

class MYSQLWo(Base):
....
class MYSQLWocom(Base):
....
class MP2Wo(Base2): 
....
class MP2Wocom(Base2)
```

http://groups.google.com/group/sqlalchemy/browse_thread/thread/afe09d6387a4dc69?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You can use one **db** instance with two **Model** to bypass this problem.

And this can also be used to implement a master/slave use case in Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Just like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'rw': 'rw', 'r': 'r'}
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.Model_RW = db.make_declarative_base()

class A(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'common'

class B(db.Model_RW):
    __tablename__ = 'common'
```

Comment: what are the cases where one may want to use the single db instance pattern instead of two different instances, as shown by @dangel?