# Using same name of tables with different binds in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables sharing the same name but located in different databases:

```
class Lcn(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'lcn'

class LcnRemote(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'remote'
    __tablename__ = 'lcn'
```

It seems SQLAlchemy doesn't like that. It says:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'lcn' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

Is there a way to solve this without having to rename one of my tables?

Comment: Related: [Flask-SQLAlchemy - how do sessions work with multiple databases?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38374005) and [sqlalchemy multiple databases with same table names not working](//stackoverflow.com/q/8264686)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use separate [declarative base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264686/sqlalchemy-multiple-databases-with-same-table-names-not-working) for different databases with the same name, to prevent sharing of SQLAlchemy metadata. You'll have to create two `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy()` instances:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/database1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {'remote': 'sqlite:////tmp/database1.db'}

db1 = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Lcn(db1.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'lcn'

db2 = SQLAlchemy(app)

class LcnRemote(db2.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'remote'
    __tablename__ = 'lcn'
```

This is a limitation of Flask-SQLAlchemy, it really should allow you to create declarative bases per bind. The way the `SQLAlchemy()` class currently is designed limits it to just *one* such base; it proxies various SQLAlchemy metadata calls through the `db.Model` class it generates at the start. By creating *two* instances of `flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy()` you work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this snippet. I would prefer not having to instantiate two different apps, but if that's what it takes, so be it.

Comment: @JureVrscaj: This is really a limitation of Flask SQLAlchemy; I know it supports multi-database binding, but it should *really* use separate metadata instances values for each. You could perhaps report that as a bug in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues).

Comment: @MartijnPieters is this fix now in flask?

Comment: @ManuraOmal: the fix would be applied to the Flask SQLAlchemy extension, not Flask itself. I don't know if the project has fixed this issue, I haven't followed development in the intervening time.

Comment: @ManuraOmal: I've updated my solution to avoid using two `Flask` apps.

Comment: @JureVrscaj: I've removed the need to create two separate Flask apps now. I haven't tested this extensively but this *should* work as is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters in `class LcnRemote`  it has `db2` still

Comment: @ManuraOmal: yes, that's the point. `db2.Model` is a separate declarative base from `db1.Model`, keeping the SQLAlchemy metadata separate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am facing the same issue but I am using flask app builder. Do you have any thoughts to fix that one?

Comment: @ManuraOmal: sorry, I have no experience with Flask App Builder. A quick glance shows they [subclass the `SQLAlchemy` object](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/master/flask_appbuilder/models/sqla/__init__.py), if they generate code you'll have to edit the generated code to create a second instance of that subclass.

Comment: @ManuraOmal: looking at the example code (like [this one](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder/blob/af095ac4094d068fa2dd467bd01fa8b95d697fc1/examples/quickcharts/app/__init__.py)), that should be simple enough.

Comment: I know I'm resurrecting an old one but this was the first google result for my search. The method of calling `SQLAlchemy(app)` twice no longer works in Flask-SQLAlchemy, it gives a warning that `A 'SQLAlchemy' Instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.`